# why Console.log(req.body.post) give correct id but using it in Post.findById return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I am using `req.body.post` in `Post.findById` it gives `undefined` but when I use direct `id` in `Post.findById` it workes fine.
`Console.log(req.body.post)` give correct id but using it in `Post.findById`
gives `undefined`
why `undefined` while console.log give correct id

```
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports.create = function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.post);
    Post.findById(req.body.post,function(err,post){
        console.log(post);
        return res.redirect('/');
    })
}
```

```
Output
62175534d37c9ce165033cee 
undefined
```

when I use direct id which is `console.log` print then it works fine.

```
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports.create = function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.post);
    Post.findById('62175534d37c9ce165033cee',function(err,post){
        console.log(post);
        return res.redirect('/');
    })
}
```

```
Output
{
  comment: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("62175534d37c9ce165033cee"),        
  content: 'sdf',
  user: new ObjectId("621749248e7de90faa6263d4"),       
  createdAt: 2022-02-24T09:51:48.621Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-02-24T09:51:48.621Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: You should check `console.log(err)` as well

Comment: It might just be how you've typed this into your question but you have a trailing space in the output from `console.log(req.body.post)`. Try `req.body.post.trim()`

Comment: `req.body.post.trim()`  worded fine thenks

Comment: Check your frontend code then as that's where the extra space comes from

Comment: but from where I am learning he use req.body.post and it worked

Comment: yes, get it is was space in front end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242712/discussion-between-vishal-singh-and-phil).

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` output can sometimes be misleading, if you log an object expression. It may print a value that was not yet set at the time, when the code execution reached the `console.log()` statement (look here, for example: [console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync))

To be on the safe side with your logging output, modify your code like this:

```
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports.create = function(req,res){
    const stringToLog = req.body.post;
    console.log(stringToLog);
    Post.findById(req.body.post,function(err,post){
        console.log(post);
        return res.redirect('/');
    })
}
```

Don't be surprised if this leads to a different result (or maybe it doesn't).

Answer (score -1):

You need to import ObjectId from mongodb.
Than you try to find id like next:

db.colection_name.find(ObjectId('621749248e7de90faa6263d4'))

As you see in your database, it's not just a simple string, it's an object.

ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: Why does the string literal work then?

Comment: Given OP's code uses _models_, I'd say they're using [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)